# Npm installing react-viro

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I want to test the `react-Viro` npm package on windows machine, but I am facing trouble when executing the `npm install` command

> `npm install --save @viro-community/react-viro`

I get this

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: partner@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.68.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.68.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native@"0.65.1" from @viro-community/react-viro@2.23.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@viro-community/react-viro
npm ERR!   @viro-community/react-viro@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-08T14_44_36_980Z-debug-0.log
```

although I tried `--legacy-peer-deps`

and it stopped on this message

```
reify:fsevents: sill reify mark deleted [
```

Comment: looks like you have a version of react-native installed in your main app that is not supported by react-viro since they just have 0.65.1 as peerDependency while you are running 0.68.2 that is not supported.
I think your only solution is to downgrade react-native to the supported version if everything else fails.

Comment: @leo Thanks, but what can I do if there is a package works only with the `0.68.2` version how can I implement both packages?